# Why is Vout less than Vcc here in a way disproportionate to beta?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, charging, schmitt-trigger, square

Given: Vcc=9V, duty cycle = 0.5, oscillation frequency=500Hz
Note that I am not interested in electronics in any way (I'm planning to continue as a web developer yet need to finish my CCE major) so I might lack some basic understanding on my part; please do not be harsh.[[image: (Vout,Vin) vs T][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iGSw.png)

[image: My circuit]

Comment: What have you done so far to answer this question?

Comment: I picked two values for R3 and R4 for the fosc equation; I chose R2 and solved for C in the fosc equation; I ran the transient analysis in order to obtain Vout and Vin; I tried varying the resistors as R3=12k and R4 = 15k to no avail.

Comment: Clarify the problem please. Which "beta" ? Your post does not even contain that word or symbol ?

Comment: Beta is R3/R3+R4. It is also Vout/Vin

Comment: This oscillator circuit is meant to saturate its output, It can be exactly the supply voltage or less depending on the actual op-amp model.

Comment: I'm using the ua741 model. In other circuits the output was the same as intended, except that I used diodes to limit it. So without diodes, it is normal to have a value slightly less than Vcc?

Comment: It does not depend on diodes or not, but on the circuit you build. If you set up a circuit which drives the output to of the op-amp into saturation, then yes it is normal that the output will be near or at the supplies. If you build a circuit that keeps the output at an intermediate level, then the output will be - well - at an intermediate level. Are you sure, you understand how this circuit works ?

Comment: I'm not really sure if I do. All I know is that it's a square wave generator based on a Schmitt trigger and that we need it to charge and discharge the capacitor. Other than that I'm just applying the equations.

Comment: I believe if you spend a little time to read up, how the output level of an op-amp is determined and how it reacts to changes of its input voltage, you will be able to easily understand this question and many more.

Comment: Noted, thank you for the heads-up and the explanations, really appreciated

Comment: in a nutshell: the op-amp will always try to equalize the voltage at its two inputs..It attempts this by raising the output if in+ > in- and by lowering the output if in- > in+. if you plot in+, in- and out you should be able to understand why they change as they do.

Comment: It's a 741. Besides being a fossil, it does not have rail to rail output stage, so it is only capable of an output voltage a few volts away from the power supply. Check "output voltage" spec in datasheet.

Comment: What's the problem? Your output oscillates almost between +9V and -9V (not exactly Vcc and Vee because of the uA741 not being a rail-to-rail OP-amp). What were you expecting?

Comment: I was expecting Vcc for some reason. My understanding of electronics is not good, to say the least. Glad to know that this graph is normal.

Comment: The lousy 741 opamp design is 53 years old. It was designed when "rail-to-rail" was not even thought about. The datasheet shows up to a 4V output voltage loss to Vcc and to Vee.

Comment: To expand on @tobalt’s contribution, op amps are not intelligent, they (always) output a voltage that is equal to the voltage on the non-inverting input minus the voltage on the inverting input, multiplied by a large factor.  With a certain amount of negative feedback this forms a voltage amplifier although they can be used in a number of other ways.

Comment: @tobalt,  that "tries to equalise" is only true where there's negative feedback. this circuit doesn't really have that.

Comment: @Jasen agreed, better to say 'the designer can use the behavior to make the inputs equalize, by implementing a negative feedback path.'

Answer (score 1):

Real electronic parts are all imperfect, much of the work of electronics design is learning the imperfections of each available part and picking the right compromises.

UA741 being an "antique" design is far from perfect. as you have discovered one of its failings is that its output doesn't go all the way to VCC or to VEE